# Add item to cart and product options

Tags: magento-1.9, product, quoteitem

I want to add item to cart programatically so I used this piece of code.

```
$result = $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionId, 4, array(array(
    'product_id' => '4',
    'sku' => 'simple_product',
    'qty' => '5',
    'options' => array(
        13 => '1000',
        14 => '10002',
        15 => '10001',
        16 => '10002',
    ),
    'bundle_option' => null,
    'bundle_option_qty' => null,
    'links' => null
)));
```

As you can noticed there are four options which are required. According to documentation key is a id of the option so i used ID and put the value but I stil get exception "**Please specify the product required option(s).**" but there is no more required option. Did I something wrong? option ids are for sure good.

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the `bundle_option` , `bundle_option_qty` and `links` array entries ?

Comment: the same exception. For a test I set this option to non-required and it works well so it looks like the keys in array are wrong but in the database i can see that thouse ids are correct. I'm confused.

Comment: Try to manually add this product to your cart and log the corresponding options to see if that matches.